# Mon projet Québec immigration application IELTS confusion

Tags: immigration, canada, ielts

I submitted my application successfully within the August 16-22, 2016, intake period. The IELTS information I provided was based on academic, not general training, scores (Speaking 5.5, Listening, Reading and Writing 6). I did this because my IELTS GT was out of date, and I wasn't able to sit another test before the August deadline.

Is this going to be a problem?  Would I be able to take another IELTS and provide updated scores? My other factors (i.e., education, qualifications etc.) are okay.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a direct reference on the Quebec immigration site, except that you must have at least [CLB level 5](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/immigrate-settle/permanent-workers/requirements-programs/language-knowledge.html). The [main Canadian immigration site](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/tools/language/charts.asp) has an equivalency chart for only the general IELTS test, not the Academic version.

I found a note on another page that after submitting your application that you should have received an email that would allow you update certain information. It looks like you might be able to update the language test scores but perhaps only within 90 days of submission. See [section 1.2 Language Knowledge](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/informations/questions-answers.html) on the Questions and Answers page.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the actual English IELTS  test ?

If you are applying at immigration from anywhere within **QUEBEC** *(extension of stay following  skilled contract, Permanent residency or citizenship)* You are required to pass the **FRENCH** test, and the English become secondary when it comes to Immigration purpose. It is the only province that requires it and that does not prioritize English. Again, this is toward long term stay. You will have a written test as well as spoken/listen for a time frame of every 3-6 months (depending on your progress). They are really serious about this and if you do not show any significant progress, you permit might be revoked and your immigration demand refused.

This might not answer exactly your question,but no matter on what you based your information, it isn't a strong requirements as in Ontario. I want to make sure you got all the information, as I know people that have been mislead like that and were only caring for English and they had poor outcomes.

Believe me, I know how they work, been dealing with them more than enough. I was in charge of immigration department and all government matters for 7 years with my previous company.

Comment: Please avoid using profanity.